# GDAL WMS service won't accept HTTPS connections

Tags: gdal, wms, curl

We have a system that is using the GDAL C# wrappers to talk to a WMS server. This all works ok when using HTTP, but if we try and connect to the same server using HTTPS then the call to GDAL. Open fails and the message "https not supported or disabled in libCurl" is output in the debug log.  The HTTPS connection works OK with applications.

Looking online seems to indicate that libcurl doesn't like URLs with single quotes or spaces in them, but the URL we pass to GDAL has double-quotes.

It seems an obvious thing that GDAL would support HTTPS connections to WMS servers (or it does to me) so has anyone got this functionality working before, and if so, what's the secret?

We are using GDAL 1.11.0 and libCurl 7.18.

Comment: Welcome, @DCB! If you are in doubt about how to ask, please visit  https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, consider spending some time in the Markdown help section https://gis.stackexchange.com/editing-help to improve the formatting of your questions. And if you can, help the community!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried the following

```
gdalinfo /vsicurl/https://labs.webgeodatavore.com/partage/S2A_MSIL1C_20170102T111442_N0204_R137_T30TXT_20170102T111441_TCI_no_ovr_strip.tif
```

and "it works" on my computer (Ubuntu 18.04), so clearly and environment issue (Dotnet level or more probably libcurl dll). You may try using this HTTPS URL to see if it changes from the behaviour on your computer `https://labs.webgeodatavore.com/partage/S2A_MSIL1C_20170102T111442_N0204_R137_T30TXT_20170102T111441_TCI_no_ovr_strip.tif`

Did you also see if `curl-config --protocols` contains HTTPS? If not, the problem is that you are using GDAL compiled with a CURL without HTTPS support. You need to recompile CURL with the right flag, then recompile GDAL against this CURL.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need to update our libCurl, didn't realise it was so out of date.